# Excess characters error when trying to use HaskellNet for IMAP

Tags: haskell, imap

Thought I'd try to experiment again with Haskell to build a simple imap client. I tried the simple example that comes with HaskellNet  (see below). However, I get the error

> user error (BAD: parse error: excess characters at end of command)

From inserting print statements, I've determined that this is being caused by the login function. Any idea how to fix this?

```
main = do
  con <- connectIMAPPort imapServer imapPort
  login con username password
  mboxes <- list con
  mapM print mboxes
  select con "INBOX"
  msgs <- search con [ALLs]
  mapM_ (\x -> print x) (take 4 msgs)
  forM_ (take 4msgs) (\x -> fetch con x >>= print)
```

Comment: Does your password have spaces? Do you have any way of capturing the output it generates?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but are you on Windows by any chance? If so, it could be related to the `\r\n` vs `\n` thing.

Comment: I'm on OS X (10.10). No spaces but there is a '%' character in the password. If either spaces or a special character is screwing things up then it doesn't well for the reliability of HaskellNet. I have no idea how to capture output. This experiment was going to be my one last shot at trying to use Haskell for something real but I'm not expert.

Comment: Try placing quotes around the password.  I suspect the library may not automatically quote the password.

Comment: Thank you --- that did it. I put  \" at each end of the password.

Comment: I will change my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing quotes around the password. I suspect the library may not automatically quote the password.

Answer (score 0):

Due to this question the bug was fixed in [version 0.4.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-0.4.1/changelog) of HaskellNet, so if you upgrade to the new version you can just enter the password as it is (without quoting it).

Comment: Nice --- unfortunately the 'fetch' command doesn't work so I had to give up and switch to Python (sigh).

Comment: Just for grins I got the update and now 'fetch' seems to work. Very strange (and frustrating)

Comment: Yes, the [problem with the fetch](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/HaskellNet/issues/27) was also known and fixed in [0.4.1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet). If you find more problems, please feel free to ask or [report it in github](https://github.com/jtdaugherty/HaskellNet/issues/).